# slideUp is not working on button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hi experts i'm new to jquery & here when i click on 'change alternate email' link the box is sliding down but when click on save button actually it should slide Up but it didn't.
Here is my code.

HTML:

```
<div class="form-group alternate-email-box">
<div class="row margin-lft-right-0">
<div class="col-sm-10 pad-left-zero">
<input type="email" class="form-control" name="alternate-email">
</div>
<div class="col-sm-2">
<button type="button" class="btn pi-btn btn-radius">Save <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-right right-arrow-head-icon alternate-email-btn"></span></button>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Jquery:

```
$('.alternate-email').click(function(){
        $('.alternate-email-box').slideDown();
        return false;
    });
 $('.alternate-email-btn').click(function(){
        $('.alternate-email-box').hide();
        return false;
    });
```

Comment: Use `slideUp()` not `hide()` and attach event handler with `btn`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to use

```
$('.alternate-email').click(function(){
        $('.alternate-email-box').slideDown();
        return false;
    });
 $('.alternate-email-btn').click(function(){
        $('.alternate-email-box').slideUp();
        return false;
 });
```

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/pbvb7fm5/

Answer (score 0):

mine is ok,are you sure you have run the code on more than 1 browser to see the result?maybe your css conflict with [slideUp()](http://api.jquery.com/slideUp/)

```js
$('.alternate-email').click(function(){
        $('.alternate-email-box').slideDown();
        return false;
    });
 $('.alternate-email-btn').click(function(){
        $('.alternate-email-box').slideUp();
        return false;
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>



<div class="form-group alternate-email-box">
<div class="row margin-lft-right-0">
<div class="col-sm-10 pad-left-zero">
<input type="email" class="form-control" name="alternate-email">
</div>
<div class="col-sm-2">
<button type="button" class="btn pi-btn btn-radius">Save <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-right right-arrow-head-icon alternate-email-btn"></span></button>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

To solve this and to have better control over the elements you are searching for (like save btn) use an Id on the html elements. Something like below:

```js
$('.alternate-email').click(function(){
        $('.alternate-email-box').slideDown();
        return false;
    });
 $('#btnSave').click(function(){
        $('.alternate-email-box').slideUp();
        return false;
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<div class="form-group alternate-email-box">
<div class="row margin-lft-right-0">
<div class="col-sm-10 pad-left-zero">
<input type="email" class="form-control" name="alternate-email">
</div>
<div class="col-sm-2">
<button type="button" class="btn pi-btn btn-radius" id="btnSave">Save <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-right right-arrow-head-icon alternate-email-btn"></span></button>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Following Html code.

```
<div class="form-group alternate-email-box">
<div class="row margin-lft-right-0">
<div class="col-sm-10 pad-left-zero">
<input type="email" class="form-control" name="alternate-email">
</div>
<div class="col-sm-2">
<button type="button" class="btn pi-btn btn-radius alternate-email-btn">Save </button>
</div>
</div>
</div>

<span class="alternate-email">change alternate email</span>
```

Your span has no effect and use the button class (alternate-email-btn) inside buton tag
`<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-right right-arrow-head-icon alternate-email-btn"></span>`

When You are hiding alternate-email-box class it only hides your section without any animation. Use slideUp and slideDown will give you the effect. You can also use slideToggle(). Like

```
   $('.alternate-email-box').slideToggle();
```

Or use some id

```
$('#button').click(function() {
  $('.alternate-email-box').slideUp();
  return false;
});`
```